# Push notification with service worker in mozilla firefox

Tags: node.js, push-notification, service-worker, push-api

I am new to service worker and trying to learn it. I am implementing push notification using service worker. I am looking for simple demo code for pushing at server side and receive at client side notification as a reference in developing my web application. Suggestions will be very helpful. I am using node.js for implemention.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the examples in the [Web Push category of the ServiceWorker Cookbook](https://serviceworke.rs/web-push.html).

The examples are using the [web-push Node.js library](https://github.com/marco-c/web-push).

Comment: Thanks for web-push Node.js library link. Good repository with many working demo. Thanks..