# Service worker send push notifications even not on the website

Tags: javascript, push-notification, cross-browser, service-worker

I'm have a personal website and I think it will be perfect if I add the push notifications feature.

I'm new to service worker, but already know about push notification. I need the service worker that send push notification even the user isn't on my website.

How do I do that? I won't use a pay service like pushcrew. I want learn how to create it.

Comment: `send push notification even the user isn't on my website` - where will this notification be pushed to?

Comment: When user open their browser, and then a notification pop up, even their not on my website

Comment: do service workers work that way?

Comment: Take a look at the Web Push examples from the ServiceWorker Cookbook: https://serviceworke.rs/web-push.html.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Push notification with service worker in mozilla firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36912561/push-notification-with-service-worker-in-mozilla-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

First of all. You'll need to host your website on a secure i.e. HTTPS domain. You could use [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) for the same. It is free and easy to use.
Then you could go over this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web). It is pretty straightforward.
Here is an awesome [demo/sample](https://gauntface.github.io/simple-push-demo/).

To give you a head-start, service workers are separate js files that are registered with the user's browser. After the user is registered and subscribed a URL is generated which can be used to invoke the user's browser(serviceworker.js) (These will be invoked even if your website is not open). So you are supposed to communicate that URL back to your servers for all the users and invoke all those URLs if you are sending a push-notification to everyone. Cheers!